# How do I describe a baby's cry?

Tags: word-choice

How I describe a baby's cry in writing like the way baby Fig cried off-screen in part [three of the movie Barney's Great Adventure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EpX2DzhuA0)? Do I just say, the baby started to cry, or the baby began to cry? What do I say? and similar type of sounding cries.

Answer (score 2):

## What is the significance?

The actual cry in this video is pretty soft. But the specifics don't matter as much as what you are trying to achieve in the scene.

That impact do you want the baby's crying to make? Are you creating sympathy for the overburdened mother dealing with the infant? Describe the cry as a demanding howl. Is this a bad mother? Then the cry might be a desperate keening wail. Has the family been murdered except for the kid? Then it could be a plaintive, neglected whimper. Do we want this to be kind of cute? Then it can be a baby's gentle call. Is the child being eaten by a Hyena?

Let's not go there.

But decide what the motive is for having the cry there, then use words and descriptors that evoke the feeling you want to cause. ***(If you want a specific take, tell me what the goal is in comments, if you are able, and I'll get back to you. Otherwise modify your question and I'll check back***).